# Response.Redirect will Lost ViewState?

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, viewstate

Suppose, on Page_Load() of a page (WebForms) that I create this Control :

```
HtmlGenericControl optionBox = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
optionBox.Attributes["class"] = "class_1";
```

Than, a use will recall the page using a LinkButton. On the method called from this button, I change the class of my previous div :

```
protected void cmdCerca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "class_2");
    ...
}
```

Well, if I watch on the rendered result, I'll see that the class of the div have been changed.

This means that, in the next call to this page (from this context, example calling `cmdCerca_2_Click`), that object will be recovered from the View, getting `class_2`, not `class_1`.

But, this doesnt happens if, at the end of `cmdCerca_Click`, I call the same page with `Response.Redirect()`. Seems that the View will be lost.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: This is the intended behavior.

Comment: I'd try to avoid the redirect

Comment: I need redirect before I need to construct the GET query string for a search form. So in the future, pasting the same query, I get the same results...! intended behavior... why? Is there a reason?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the controls in the page init event, rather than load, in order to get them into the control tree.

You must be recreating this control on every postback?  In this case, your default class will be set every time.

Comment: Why Page_Init and not Page_Load? Am I missing some?